# What is the difference between literary review and abstract

Tags: thesis

My undergraduate dissertation requires a literary review and an abstract.
I have been reading published papers similar to my topic but which are mostly at masters level and all of them have an abstract but no literary review.

So what is the difference between a literary review and abstract?
My understanding is the literary review is talking about what you have read and being critical and that an abstract introduces the dissertation. The problem is that when I start to write the literary review, it starts to become the abstract and I will just be repeating myself in the abstract. 
Furthermore, where should the literary review be placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abstract is the summary of the work you have writen. While the literature review is a summary of other literature, which you would connect together, and might derive a conclusion from